# Using strtok only works if I put the delimiter after the last item

Tags: c, strtok

So I am trying to open and read files based on stdinput. I've used strtok to parse the input so that the user can input multiple files. I've set the delimiter to space.

```
int main(const int argc, const char *argv[]){
    if (argc == 1) {
        char str[100];
        const char delim[2] = " ";
        printf("Enter a filename:\n");

        fgets(str, 100, stdin);
        char *ptr = strtok(str, delim);
        while (ptr != NULL){
            FILE *fp = fopen(ptr, "r");
            if ((fp == NULL)) {
                fprintf(stderr, "failed to open %s\n", ptr);
            }
            else{
                printf("Opening file: %s\n", ptr);
                char c;
                while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF){

                    if (c != ' '){
                        putchar(c);
                    }
                    if (c == ' ') {
                        printf("\n");
                    }

                }
                fclose(fp);
            }
            ptr = strtok(NULL, delim);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

If I input "example.txt example2.txt", it will read example.txt, and then say failed to open example2.txt. However, if I input "example.txt example2.txt " (notice the extra space), it will read both of them correctly, but it will say "failed to open" with no file name at the end. Also, reading one file by itself results in "failed to open". Any ideas?

Comment: `delim[2] = " ";` -> `delim[] = " \r\n";`

Comment: Recommend using `int main(void)` if you don't use `argc` or `argv`.  Also, `fgetc()` returns an `int`, not a `char` — you may detect EOF prematurely (if the plain `char` type is signed) or not detect it at all (if the plain `char` type is unsigned).  Use `int c;` and avoid the problems.

Answer (score 5):

`fgets()` includes the newline in the string. Since you didn't put newline in your delimiter string, the second filename is being returned as `"example2.txt\n"`, and that filename doesn't exist.

Change your delimiter to include newline:

```
const char delim[] = " \n";
```